# React testing library, TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-gui="text-grid-item"]

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm using debug and have an output like

```
 <body>
    <div>
      <div
        class="table-wrapper"
      >
        <div
          class="table-component__header"
        />
        <table
          class="test-table"
        >
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td
                class="text-grid-item"
                data-testid="text-grid-item"
              >
                test table data
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot
            class="table_footer"
          >
            <tr>
              <td />
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

but if I try to access `text-grid-item` like

```
test('Given table element is text, when rendered, text table class should be returned', () => {
        const imageTableTest: TableProps = givenTableWithElement([
            {
                text: 'test table data',
                display: {
                    mobile: true,
                    wrap: false
                }
            }
        ])

        const { debug } = render(
            <Table {...imageTableTest} />
        )
        debug()

        const { getByTestId } = render(
            <Table {...imageTableTest} />
        )

        const gridItemText = getByTestId('text-grid-item').innerHTML
        expect(gridItemText).toBe('test table data')
    })
```

I get an error like

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-gui="text-grid-item"]
```

Why can't id find the `data-testid="text-grid-item"` when it's there